# Flutter - How to read json object with two lists?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, deserialization, dio

I have a json like this:

```
                  {
"data": [
{
  "id": "99412",
  "type": "post_list_item",
  "attributes": {
    "message": "@:user/3 \n@:user/77 \n@:user/52 @:user/3921 @:user/267 @:user/5 \n\nWhich sector will outperform in 2023 ???",
    "visibility": "public_visible",
    "created_at": "2023-01-07T14:38:00.691+05:30",
    "updated_at": "2023-01-07T14:38:00.779+05:30",
    "meta_info": null,
    "type": "Post",
    "likes_count": 8,
    "replies_count": 2,
    "widgets_data": [],
    "is_liked": false,
    "is_bookmarked": false,
    "is_deleted": false,
    "share_count": null
  },
  "relationships": {
    "user": {
      "data": {
        "id": "86806",
        "type": "user"
      }
    },
    "poll": {
      "data": {
        "id": "483",
        "type": "poll"
      }
    },
    "tagged_users": {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "3",
          "type": "user"
        },
        {
          "id": "5",
          "type": "user"
        },
        {
          "id": "52",
          "type": "user"
        },
        {
          "id": "77",
          "type": "user"
        },
        {
          "id": "267",
          "type": "user"
        },
        {
          "id": "3921",
          "type": "user"
        }
      ]
    },
    "tagged_companies": {
      "data": []
    },
    "tagged_topics": {
      "data": []
    },
    "tagged_instruments": {
      "data": []
    },
    "stories": {
      "data": []
    },
    "attachments": {
      "data": []
    },
    "media_files": {
      "data": []
    }
  }
},
{
  "id": "99548",
  "type": "post_list_item",
  "attributes": {
    "message": "   \n\nSGX Nifty up by 132 pts indicating a strong open 
   today. FIIs sold Rs 29 Bn while DIIs bought Rs 10.8 Bn of stocks on Friday.\n\nIndia surpasses Japan to become world's 3rd largest auto market in 2022: SIAM report\n\nDr Lal PathLabs, leader in North India, expands in West India. Subsidiary opens apex lab in Mumbai - all nearby samples to be tested here instead of Delhi (positive).\n\nIL&FS pays 5 PSU Banks 87% of their ₹1,500 crore dues. Canara, Union Bank, Central, Punjab & Sind Bank.\n\nEV scooter co. Ather Energy to achieve $1 billion in revenue in 2023 and turn profitable in few years. Beneficiary: Hero Motors\n\nOutstanding dues by power distributors (discoms) to producers (gencos) has nearly halved to Rs 62,681 cr in last 1 year. Benficiary: PFC, REC (but priced in).\n\nSolar panel manufacters boost production as costs fall for polysilicon and wafer (RM for solar cells). Positive for Sterling Wilson Renewables, Borosil Renewables.\n\n1/2",
    "visibility": "public_visible",
    "created_at": "2023-01-09T09:05:41.226+05:30",
    "updated_at": "2023-01-09T09:05:41.277+05:30",
    "meta_info": null,
    "type": "Post",
    "likes_count": 4,
    "replies_count": 1,
    "widgets_data": [],
    "is_liked": false,
    "is_bookmarked": false,
    "is_deleted": false,
    "share_count": null
  },
  "relationships": {
    "user": {
      "data": {
        "id": "83681",
        "type": "user"
      }
    },
    "poll": {
      "data": null
    },
    "tagged_users": {
      "data": []
    },
    "tagged_companies": {
      "data": []
    },
    "tagged_topics": {
      "data": []
    },
    "tagged_instruments": {
      "data": []
    },
    "stories": {
      "data": []
    },
    "attachments": {
      "data": []
    },
    "media_files": {
      "data": []
    }
  }
},  ],


           "included": [
{
  "id": "86806",
  "type": "user",
  "attributes": {
    "display_name": "Ravi Gupta",
    "username": "ravigupta132",
    "dp_thumbnail": "/rails/active_storage/representations/proxy/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBBZ2E4IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--763b2ccc4372862bb99de6620aa9fe9661693603/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdCem9MWm05eWJXRjBTU0lJYW5CbkJqb0dSVlE2RkhKbGMybDZaVjkwYjE5c2FXMXBkRnNIYVFHQWFRR0EiLCJleHAiOm51bGwsInB1ciI6InZhcmlhdGlvbiJ9fQ==--7b4a499a9ad66d05dd5deec71f9adfd36a29feb5/image_cropper_1672468958147.jpg",
    "market_view": "neutral"
  },
  "relationships": {}
},
{
  "id": "483",
  "type": "poll",
  "attributes": {
    "question": "@:user/3 \n@:user/77 \n@:user/52 @:user/3921 @:user/267 @:user/5 \n\nWhich sector will outperform in 2023 ???",
    "options": [
      "Metal",
      "PSU banks",
      "IT",
      "Infrastructure"
    ],
    "vote_count": 52,
    "grouped_count": null,
    "ends_at": "2023-01-14T14:38:01.760+05:30",
    "my_vote": null,
    "is_expired": false
  },
  "relationships": {
    "base_post": {
      "data": {
        "id": "99412",
        "type": "post"
      }
    }
  }
},  ]
```

}

Basically, 2 lists in an object.

I am unable to deserialize this data. How do I de-serialize this data to get 2 lists? I need to get data based on a common id.

This is what I have currently (WIP):

```
          Future<List<Datum>> getPostData() async {
        try {
          Response response = await _dio.get(url);
          var jsonData = response.data;
          //Map<String, dynamic> postMap = response.data;
          final someMappedObjectList = <Datum>[];
          for (var map in jsonData["data"]) {
            Datum someObject = Datum(
                id: map["id"],
                type: map["type"],
                attributes: map["attributes"],
                relationships: map["relationships"]);

            //final someObject = Datum.fromJson(map);
            someMappedObjectList.add(someObject);
          }
          //List<dynamic> listDatum = postMap["data"].toList();
          //List<Datum> listDatum = Datum.fromJson(jsonData["data"]) as List<Datum>;
          return someMappedObjectList;
        } //
        catch (e) {
          print(e);
          return [];
        }
      }

      Future<List> getPostIncluded() async {
        try {
          Response response = await _dio.get(url);
          var jsonData = response.data;
          Map<String, dynamic> postMap = response.data;

          List<dynamic> listIncluded = postMap["included"].toList();

          return listIncluded;
        } //
        catch (e) {
          print(e);
          return [];
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Especially for something this complex, I strongly suggest using the [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) package. It will save you quite a bit of trouble in the long term.

Comment: I already created the models using quitype.io. Does json_serializable do something different? I don't think it does...